# Grid Based DP: How do we tweak the Travelling Salesman Problem to work with Grids

Tags: dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman, square-grid

The question is:

> There is a n x n grid (Maze) which has either 0, 1 or 2. 0 means a path
>   exists, 1 means the cell is blocked and 2 means there exists gold in
>   that cell.  Task is to start from 0, 0 and cover the grid such that
>   all the gold is collected and then returned to a specific cell (x, y)
>   in the grid. This task has to be done in the minimum number of steps.
>
> Example:
>   Input: Maze = {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1} and
>   x = 1, y = 1
>   (return to this cell)
>
> Output: 1 as there is only 1 gold (in 1,1) and we are to return also in
>   (1,1) so 1 move is what we need.

Reading the question, I can speculate that this is perhaps a variant of the traveling salesman problem but I cannot think of how I should be applying it here. Also, since in Travelling Salesman we return back to the source node and here we do not, I am having second thoughts if this has TSP like implementation. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Travelling Sales Man is NP-complete. This problem isn't, it has an easy polynomial time solution. Don't go there.

Comment: What is a polynomial time solution for this problem?